# How to draw dashed lines as the slice separators on a pie chart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm having issues finding how to draw a dashed line as the separators on a pie chart with ios-charts. Do you know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation says it's not possible (as in you can't set the separator as dashed lines) or if the header does not provide that feature, then I would fork the library, and dig into the method that draws the pie chart and add an instance variable that allows you to set the separator as dashed lines.